# Android 4.4.2 not automatically connecting to wifi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

I have a samsung galaxy tab 3 8.0 running android 4.4.2 unrooted. My tablet is not automatically connecting to wifi networks. It was previously automatically connecting to two wifi networks (both are home networks secured with a password) but now I have to re-enter the password every time I try to connect to either of these networks. How can I get my tablet to remember the wifi networks?

Comment: well, that's something weird try removing and re-adding the network connection and see if that makes any difference !

Answer (score 1):

Try Factory resetting the tablet or if you don't want to do that then try shutting down the tablet and then turning it back on,then remove the network and then re-add it.

Comment: I already tried this. Multiple times.

Answer (score -3):

Just restart the tablet it's annoying but it works for me

Comment: That's a work-around at best – or did one reboot solve the issue permanently for you?